# can i declare a variable with name Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i am trying to declare a variable in MVC model with the name "Model" and  use it in aspx view
i have written a sample code for this.
model:

```
public int id { get; set; }
public bool Model { get; set; }
```

view:

```
      <%@Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication1.Models.account>"  %>
      <% using (Html.BeginForm("modelsubmit","Home"))
      {%>
       <%: Html.EditorFor(x =>x.id) %>
       <%: Html.EditorFor(x =>x.Model) %>
Action :-

       var model = new account();
              model.id = 1;
               model.Model = true;
             return View(model);
```

Post Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult modelsubmit(account acc)
{
    if(acc.Model == true){}
    return Json(null);
}
```

but it is throwing me error saying "parameter cannot be null".
it is  not throwing error  for  any other variables.
i am even specifying the value of variable while initializing the model.

Comment: The problem might be because your `x` is null here. Because you can legally set a property for x object as Model.

Comment: Can you post the code from your action that's rendering the view in question?

Comment: i have included a sample code

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: when i try to access Model variable in view

Comment: "parameter cannot be null" is thrown when you're passing a null (obviously) for a parameter in a method call, which does not allow nulls. I'm thinking this error is actually generating somewhere else in your code and perhaps is being masked. Even if `x` was null, as suggested as a potential cause in the comments, what's being passed to `EditorFor` is an expression containing `x`. You might have problems later, but any expression, even if it won't eventually evaluate correct, is still *something*, and would not cause that error. Check for other method calls in your action and such.

Comment: the code works fine for me, like Chris Pratt say, the error is somewhere else, can you provide more of your code?

Comment: Your code as shown is fine. I suspect maybe you have a POST method where the parameter name is `model` in which case binding will fail and your model will `null`

Comment: My post code does not have a parameter name model. i have modified the question to include that code too.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger to the MVC project, setting a breakpoint on the first line within the HttpPost method and stepping through it?

Comment: it throws error in view only, it does not goes till HttpPost

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of the property to something like `MyModel`? :) This will confirm if it is due to the name (which I suppose is not the case) or anything else.